# How to create a function modelling Earth's temperature due to heat radiation over time (if it wasn't receiving heat)

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, temperature, thermal-radiation

I am trying to model the Earth's temperature cooling if the sun disappeared, by plotting Earth's temperature over time. I know that the Stefan Boltzmann law ensures that Earth would not cool at a constant rate, since the temperature would drop the rate would also drop. But I am confused as to how I could create a function using calculus that would give me Earth's temperature as a function of time, if the Sun disappeared or if the Earth wasn't receiving any heat (assuming a blackbody)

I tried to create a function using specific heat capacity and Stefan Boltzmann but it doesn't give me what I need.

I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: You and a large number of climate scientists. You are going to need to know about emissivity, heat capacity, enthalpy of fusion, and some other things. My suggestion is to make reasonable assumptions about physical parameters, and accept that it is an approximation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emissivity   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_capacity https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enthalpy_of_fusion

Answer (score 2):

If things had been simple, Earth would have been a perfect blackbody sphere with infinite thermal conductivity (and hence the same temperature everywhere) and no atmosphere. In that case the energy loss to space would have been $4\pi \epsilon \sigma R^2 T^4$ (surface area times Stefan-Boltzmann), and the total internal energy $E=(4\pi R^3/3)\rho C_V T$. So the differential equation for how it cools would be $(4\pi R^3/3)\rho C_V T' = -4\pi\epsilon\sigma R^2 T^4$ (assuming all the constants stay constant), leading to
$$T' = -\frac{3\epsilon\sigma}{\rho C_V R} T^4=-\alpha T^4$$ which has solution
$$T(t) = \left( 3 \alpha t + T(0)^{-3}\right)^{-1/3}.$$
Basically the constant $\alpha$ gives you a rate of cooling.

However, things are not that simple. First, the emissivity $\epsilon$ depends on the temperature since for lower temperatures water will turn to white ice, making it lower. Worse, there is an atmosphere that has a noticeable effect as a blanket with a cool exterior and a warmer interior ([the temperature it radiates at](https://Earth%27s%20surface%20skin%20temperature) is a cooler 214 K than the surface): this is where atmosphere models can get rather complex since different layers have different temperature. As it cools it will eventually change state (water snows out, reducing the greenhouse effect suddenly; eventually nitrogen and oxygen snows out, removing most atmosphere). To complete the complications, Earth's interior has finite thermal conductivity and will only cool more slowly; here you may want to solve the radial spherical heat equation (plus radiogenic heating, a combination of a handful of exponential decays) for the very slow cooling over the next few billion years. For very deep cooling the thermal capacity will start to change as you approach absolute zero.

This is somewhat doable if you really want to do it, but it is complicated and you will have to do a numerical calculation rather than getting any neat formula. I recommend Raymond Pierrehumbert's book *Principles of Planetary Climate* if you want equations and some code.